# C Simple Arrays & Pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
int a[] = {10, 15, 20, 25};
int b[] = {50, 60, 70, 80, 90};

int *x[] = {a, b};
int *y[] = {a + 2, b + 3};

int *p;
int *q;
int **r;

p = a;
q = y[1];
r = &q;

*p = &p[3] - y[0];
r[0][1] = **r - y[0][1];
```

What are the contents of a and b at the end?

I figured out that `*p` is `a[0]`, and `&p[3] - y[0]` is just 3 - 2, so `a[0] = 3 - 2 = 1`. Therefore, `a[] = {1, 10, 15, 20}` (correct me if I am wrong), but `b[]` is where I get lost. I have no idea how the last line of the code works. No idea on what `r[0][1]` refers to, so getting the contents for b[] is confusing. P.S. this is for C.

Comment: Just compiling your code with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) then running it step by step in a debugger (`gdb`) would have given you the answer quicker. But beware of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'm fairly new to C (and programming in general) so I didn't know using a debugger would have given me the answer, thanks for letting me know. I never thought of it because this particular problem was given to me on paper, so I thought it was testing me on my step-by-step mental process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that the identity `*(p + k) == p[k]` (or `p + x == &p[k]`) means that you can always rewrite dereferencing as indexing and vice-versa, so if an expression is confusing you can try a different form and see if it makes more sense.

I personally find indexing easier to reason about:

Since `r = &q`, both `r[0]` and `*r` are the same as `q`:

```
q[1] = *q - y[0][1];
```

or

```
q[1] = q[0] - y[0][1];
```

`q` is `y[1]` gives:

```
y[1][1] = y[1][0] - y[0][1];
```

`y[0]`is  `a + 2` and `y[1]` is `b + 3`:

```
(b + 3)[1] = (b + 3)[0] - (a + 2)[1];
```

which is

```
*(b + 3 + 1) = *(b + 3 + 0) - *(a + 2 + 1);
```

which is

```
*(b + 4) = *(b + 3) - *(a + 3);
```

which is

```
b[4] = b[3] - a[3];
```

that is,

```
b[4] = 80 - 25;
```

Comment: Your process is akin to that of substitution in algebra. I'm very careful with it as I don't know if there are any consequences in using substitution. Should I be careful? It looks like it worked out fine. Also, using r[0] as q before r had anything to do with array is okay? Or is *r = r[0] by definition whether arrays are involved or not?

Comment: @JohnDoe There are no side effects on either side of the assignment side, so substitution is safe. And `*r == *(r + 0) == r[0]` by definition.

Answer (score 2):

The line `int **r;` declares a pointer to an `int *`. In other words, `r` is a pointer to a pointer to an int. If you recall that the syntax `x[y]` is equivalent to `*(x + y)`, you might get an idea for what `r[0][1]` does.

`r[0][1] --> *((*(r + 0)) + 1)`

Keeping in mind that `r[0][1]` is on the LHS of the assignment operator, you are storing to that memory location.

Comment: Ahh, okay. If I'm understanding it correctly,  
  
r[0][1]      --> *((*(r + 0)) + 1)  
  --> *((q) + 1)  
  --> *((b + 3) + 1)  
  --> *(b + 4)  
  --> b[4]  

So,   
  
b[4] = **r - y[0][1]  
b[4] = 80 - y[0][1]  
  
Following the same steps above, y[0][1] --> a[3]  
  
So,  
  
b[4] = 80 - 25  
b[4] = 55  
  
Thus, b[] = {50, 60, 70, 80, 55}. Is that correct?  
  
And I must ask, is my a[] correct? (i.e. a[] = {1, 15, 20, 25})